# Is there a way to have custom functions automatically load in QGIS on start up?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a custom function for the print composer that prints out copyrights, but every time I start QGIS up and go to the Print Composer for the first time, I have to the Insert Expression > Function Editor > Select the function > Ok

This is awkward enough for me, but it's only going to get worse when I roll out QGIS out (to mostly replace another GIS) to my users.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? In 2.16.0, this should be automatic and works for me when I make a custom expression for a label, save the project and restart QGIS. Also note that custom expressions are saved locally in `.qgis2/python/expressions`, something you may need to consider when rolling it out to others.

Comment: We're using 2.14 as I think this is supposed to be the Long Term Support.

I'll check out 2.16 as this would solve this particular issue.

Comment: I've had a look at this in 2.16 and i'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

New answer:
This problem happen only with windows users.
Here is a workaround with QGIS 3.X:
You can create a script called `startup.py` that will run when QGIS starts and place it at the properly folder.
[here is a official doc about](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html?highlight=startup#running-python-code-when-qgis-starts).

To register a function, use `QgsExpression.registerFunction(func)` imported from `qgis.core`.

Here is an example code (Github) [click Here](https://github.com/kylefelipe/qgis-tips-tricks/blob/master/python/scripts/load_functions/startup.py).

Comment: Additionally, to use a network drive to share startup.py across users, set the environmental variable PYQGIS_STARTUP to the .py location